# .get() and .find() for search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

So I have a search bar on a page (/Search), and when the user searches for something, it will run a filter on the input text and refresh the page with the filtered results.

If someone searched the word "monkey", the URL of the search results will be

> /Search?searchBoxText=monkey

I'm trying to make that happen without having to refresh the page.

So in my main.js I have:

```
$(function () { 
    $("#searchBox").keyup(function (e) {
        var searchBoxText= $("#searchBox").val();
        $.get("/Search?searchBoxText=" + searchBoxText, function (getHtml) {
            $("#resultsDiv").html(getHtml);
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that it displays the whole body of the page in `#resultsDiv` and I want it to just display `#resultsDiv`. So it displays the header, search bar & button again.

Essentially I want to display the new results (which would be in `#resultsDiv`) in the old `#resultsDiv` but I can't seem to constrain the .get() to only get a specific element from the resulting page.

I tried to do

- `$.get("/Search?searchBoxText=" + searchBoxText + " #resultsDiv", function (getHtml)`
- `$("#resultsDiv").html(getHtml).find("#resultsDiv");`

And other alterations like that but nothing seemed to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try following

```
$("#resultsDiv").html($(getHtml).filter("#resultsDiv"));
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/amangxpm/)**

Comment: `getHtml` is a string so won't have the `find()` method

Comment: Yeah this doesn't work. I believe it was one of the things I tried

Comment: Still doesn't work. I get the console error message: 
"Uncaught TypeError: getHtml.filter is not a function"

Comment: @Sadikhasan Oops. I don't know if you saw my comment before I deleted it but that error wasn't related. I just missed it before. Although your method still doesn't work, there is no error message in console.